# Objects cache with references counter

Tags: c++, qt, caching

I want to create a C++ objects factory that will create some objects by id. Each object must have a references counter. If an object with the same id is requested again, the same object must be returned if it's still in memory.

While there is something keeping a pointer to an object, this object will not be deleted. When there is no pointers to the object but pointer in factory cache, this object is placed in QCache and will be deleted if it will not be requested again for some time.

What's the best way to implement this?

Comment: Your factory could hand out `shared_ptr`s and itself keep a `weak_ptr`. Then, when the ID is requested again, you try to `lock()` the `weak_ptr`. If you succeed, you hand out the resulting `shared_ptr`, and if you fail, you make a new object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it.

First of all, the `factory` class would only hold **observing pointers** to the objects it instantiates. This way, objects will be immediately deleted when no owning references to them exist, without putting them in a queue.

Then, the `factory` class would return **shared pointers** to the objects it instantiates, and those shared pointers would specify a **custom deleter** to unregister the deleted object from the factory's map upon destruction.

Assuming that the objects you want to instantiate have a constructor which accept their ID as an argument, and a function `get_id()` to return their ID, here is the code for the factory class:

```
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::placeholders;

template<typename T>
class factory
{

public:

    shared_ptr<T> get_instance(int id)
    {
        auto i = m_map.find(id);
        if (i == m_map.end())
        {
            return create(id);
        }
        else
        {
            shared_ptr<T> p = i->second.lock();
            if (p == nullptr)
            {
                p = create(id);
            }

            return p;
        }
    }

    shared_ptr<T> create_instance()
    {
        shared_ptr<T> p = create(nextId);
        nextId++;
        return p;
    }

    void unregister(T* p)
    {
        int id = p->get_id();
        m_map.erase(id);
        delete p;
    }

private:

    shared_ptr<T> create(int id)
    {
        shared_ptr<T> p(new T(id), bind(&factory::unregister, this, _1));
        m_map[id] = p;
        return p;
    }

    unordered_map<int, weak_ptr<T>> m_map;
    int nextId = 0;

};
```

And that's how you would use it:

```
struct A
{
    A(int id) : _id(id) { }
    int get_id() const { return _id; }
    int _id;
};

int main()
{
    factory<A> f;

    {
        shared_ptr<A> pA = f.get_instance(5);
        shared_ptr<A> pB = pA;
        // ...
        // The object with ID 5 will go out of scope and get unregistered
    }

    shared_ptr<A> pA = f.get_instance(3);
    shared_ptr<A> pB = f.get_instance(3); // This will return the existing object
    //
    // Instance with ID 3 will go out of scope and get unregistered
}
```

Comment: This doesn't do for my task because I need a cache (object construction is slow). Also I want to make clear that custom deleter is not necessary here, one can just check if m_map item has expired or not. It seems that I found a solution and I hope I'll post it here later.